# Azure ad is intercepting touch events and opening itself

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

It's nearly impossible to scroll past this Azure ad on my phone, because it apparently intercepts touch events and then opens itself as soon as my finger is lifted.

[image: Azure ad intercepting touch events]

My browser history tends to look like this after a StackOverflow session:

[image: Azure in browser history]

Chrome 76 Android

Comment: Seems similar to [this ad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331960/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-start-audio) and [this one too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331755/microsoft-azure-advertisement-breaks-the-back-button-behaviour)

Comment: Someone at Microsoft is worrying about the pageviews.

Comment: The situation seems to be resolved. Retagging the question as [meta-tag:status-completed]. If I get it wrong, please let me know.

Comment: FWIW, it's back @NicolasChabanovsky: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349794/ads-on-android-open-regardless-of-whether-i-touch-them

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Not Azure AFAIK, but the issue has happened again on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349794/ads-on-android-open-regardless-of-whether-i-touch-them).

Comment: @Shog9 Good to see you! I've pinged the ads team about it. I hope they resolve and / or answer on MSE soon.